# The relationship was not loaded because the type is not available

Tags: entity-framework

I changed a column length on SQL db and refreshed entity model from database.  This created a foreign key relationship that DOES exist on the database and has since db creation.  When entity model was first created, the FK was NOT created. Since then, VS 2012 was updated with SQL Server Data Tools.  After entity model was refreshed, I get the message:

> The relationship 'CarrierSupportModel.FK_DriverTerminal_Driver' was
>   not loaded because the type 'CarrierSupportModel.DriverTerminal' is
>   not available" when any table associated with the FK is involved.

Hope this makes some sense.  Thanks for providing any guidance on this issue.

Comment: Do you have any duplicated classes in the model, like `DriverTerminal` and `DriverTerminal1`?